# How Cloud Messaging Works in react-native-firebase v6.x.x?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I have installed `react-native-firebase v6.2`, but Now I cant find a good help for implementing Cloud Messaging.

Can anyone help how to use Cloud Messaging without the Notifications module?

Because the Notifications module has removed from v6, And I decided to use only Cloud Messaging, but I dont know how to do it.

The permission and request for remote notification is OK.
**This is my Code I am sending to myself but it does not work on android, any help please**

```
const sendNotification = async ()=> {
    try {
        const firebaseAPIKey = "QEOEKDjjIS1E6ZDKSKJXAxdkIGk3qTb4FXCMs";
        const notifyMessage = {
            registration_ids: ["fheeeEaBwK0HM:eoOELDL6BUEdNUhRvJsjBv3x9dPLybZqqBoqJ_wzcE5_pbl-e1nnIsLhbzJd5-_R4MNhVYtuCLXWjWSguLfKTOqXR0gEfhgukdIw-AexChDjy8tI6u7f04i5xtOkaAJgU"],
            notification: {
                "title": "Muhammad Wafa",
                "body": "Hi dear this is a simple message.",
                "vibrate": 1,
                "sound": 1,
                "show_in_foreground": true,
                "priority": "high",
                "content_available": true
            }
        }

        let headers = new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `key=${firebaseAPIKey}`
        });

        let response = await fetch("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", {method: "POST", headers, body: JSON.stringify(notifyMessage)});
        console.log('response', response);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error in : sendNotification', err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If Your app is in Foreground then you'll not see any notification.

Notifications module is no longer available in react-native-firebase-v6, this means that now to show a local push notification you'll have to rely on any other library e.g. [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification). Except this, other things should work just fine.

Here is my App.js-

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
// ... other imports

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Notification caused app to open from background state
    const onNotificationOpenedListener = messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(
      remoteMessage => {
        console.log(remoteMessage, 'App.useEffect.onNotificationOpenedListener');
      }
    );

    // Check whether an initial notification is available
    // Notification caused app to open from quit state
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(remoteMessage, 'App.useEffect.getInitialNotification');
        }
      });

    // Foreground state messages
    const onMessageReceivedListener = messaging().onMessage(
      async remoteMessage => {
        // show local notification using react-native-push-notification
        showLocalPushNotification(remoteMessage);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      // unsubscribe all listeners
      onNotificationOpenedListener();
      onMessageReceivedListener();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Navigation />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

util to show local push notification-

```
// todo: implement click handler as firebase-messaging handlers are not fired
export const showLocalPushNotification = remoteMessage => {
  const { notification = {}, data = {} } = remoteMessage;
  PushNotification.localNotification({
    //smallIcon: 'ic_notification', // todo uncomment when resource is added
    channelId: '', // todo
    messageId: 'google:message_id',
    title: notification.title,
    message: notification.body,
    sound: 'default',
    data
  });
};
```

Only problem is notification handlers (`onNotificationOpenedApp/getInitialNotification`) are not fired when local notification is clicked. I can go ahead and register notification handler using react-native-push-notification but then I'll end up having two handlers for same functionality.

Yet to figure out solution for this.

My index.js-

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

// Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  // Data only messages will be ignored when app is in Background, it can be handled here
  console.log(remoteMessage, 'index.setBackgroundMessageHandler');
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

No service registration is required in AndroidManifest.xml